# How do I change output format to currency?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm trying to make the following sqlcmd output the totaled amount in USD Currency and remove unnecessary trailing 0's

```
declare @today datetime = '2015-5-2'  set nocount on;select [Day Total]  = sum(case when AccountingDate > dateadd(DAY, -1, @today) then [TotalJackpotAmount] else 0 end),        [Week Total] = sum(case when AccountingDate > dateadd(WEEK, -1, @today) then [TotalJackpotAmount] else 0 end),        [Month Total] = sum(case when AccountingDate > dateadd(MONTH, -1, @today) then [TotalJackpotAmount] else 0 end),         [Year Total] = sum([TotalJackpotAmount]) from   [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay] where [AccountingDate] <= @today and [AccountingDate] > dateadd(year, -1, @today);" -o \\support\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\handpaytest\index.html -h-1 -s "," -w 700 -W
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just convert your field/sum to decimal(18,2) like this:

```
select convert(decimal(18,2),1.235)
```

This will output 1.24

Your query will then look like this:

```
declare @today datetime = '2015-5-2'  
set nocount on;
select 
[Day Total]  = convert(decimal(18,2),sum(case when AccountingDate > dateadd(DAY, -1, @today) then [TotalJackpotAmount] else 0 end)),        
[Week Total] = convert(decimal(18,2),sum(case when AccountingDate > dateadd(WEEK, -1, @today) then [TotalJackpotAmount] else 0 end)),        
[Month Total] = convert(decimal(18,2),sum(case when AccountingDate > dateadd(MONTH, -1, @today) then [TotalJackpotAmount] else 0 end)),         
[Year Total] = convert(decimal(18,2),sum([TotalJackpotAmount]) )
from   [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay] 
where [AccountingDate] <= @today and [AccountingDate] > dateadd(year, -1, @today);
```

Answer (score 3):

I see you already accepted an answer using `CONVERT()`.  So you are aware, if you are in SQL 2012 or higher you can use `FORMAT()`, which is helpful if you also want/need to see the currency symbol.

### Syntax

```
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )
```

### Example

Code:

```
SELECT FORMAT ( 21000.15000100, 'C', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( 21000.15000100, 'C', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'
      ,FORMAT ( 21000.15000100, 'C', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'
      ,FORMAT ( 21000.15000100, 'C', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Chinese (Simplified PRC) Result';
```

Output:

[image: Currency]

### Source

[FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not aware of a whole lot.  I just became an accidental DBA admin.  All I've got for experience are three books and the internet in front of me.  And as for this particular database its SQL Server 2005.